# chrome.devtools.network.getHAR doesn't retrieve WebSocket Messages

Tags: google-chrome-extension, websocket

I need to retrieve WebSocket messages and I was planning to create a Chrome Extension which could do that by using `chrome.devtools.network.getHAR` for example.

But unfortunately it doesn't retrieve Messages or Frames sent via WebSocket.

Is it any solution available on how to retrieve WebSocket Messages / Frames?

- This is what I am trying to retrieve (using https://www.websocket.org/echo.html):

[image: Chrome Dev Tools]

- This is the code I use:

[image: JS Code]

- But no Frames data can be retrieved:

[image: Captured data]

Thank you for any suggestions in advance!

Comment: You'll probably have to intercept those messages manually using chrome.debugger API and WebSocket events in the [Network](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/) domain of the protocol.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for suggestion! Yep, it works fine with `chrome.debugger` and Network domain!